# Continuous volume shows too much available space

Tags: ssd, disk-utility, raid

I have a continuous volume of two identical SSD drives. 2 terabytes, 1.92 terabytes in practice.

I plugged it in via USB today and finder and disk utility show that all the space is available. 1.92TB.

All the files are accessible, nothing seems corrupt, they are large images and photoshop documents and lightroom archives. Moving more files to this volume decreases the available space from what is reported, 1.75TB.

Getting info about existing folders on the drive show me exactly how much space those folders take, and I can determine via subtraction how much space has been used on this volume or how much is free.

But this concerns me

GrandPerspective shows me exactly how much space has been used 841 GB

How do I get finder and the rest of the OS to report to me proper available space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Repair Disk` in Disk Utility on this volume did the trick.